# Handling data deletion in spring data jpa pagination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I have a method like the below.

```java
  public List<ResponseDto> getChanges();
```

This service returns the result, but it is a stateful method because calling another service `A`, affects the result of `getChangedAccounts()` method. For example, I have 30 items in my list, in the normal situation (when the client does not call service `A`) this method works fine (page number 1 up to 3, with page size 10), but the problem is when the client call service `A` because it changes the status of entities and that changed record does not return in `getChangedAccounts()`. So in this scenario for example the first bunch (page no=1 page size=10) has been changed during service `A` and currently, I have 20 records, so when the client calls (page no=3 page size=10) there is no result, is there any way to keep the page no order but return previous data?
I know about `hasPrevious()`, but I don't exactly what should I do.

```java
Page<Entity> changedEntities = repository.findChanges(paramA, paramB, pageable);
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(changedEntities) || ObjectUtils.isEmpty(changedEntities.getContent())) {
            if (changedEntities.getTotalElements() == 0)
                throw new NotFoundException("Not found any changes!");
            else {
                while (changedEntities.hasPrevious()){
                    Pageable pageable1 = changedEntities.previousPageable();
                }
            }
        }

 PageImpl<ResponseDto> responseDtoPage = new PageImpl<>(changedEntities.getContent()
                .stream()
                .map(ce-> new ResponseDto(ce.getMessageId(), ce.getAccountNumber()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
```